# Visualforce email template can't see data when run in unit test

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, email-template

I currently have a `Batchable` process that will send emails to some users:

```java
global class ExpiryNotificationHandler implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global System.Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return [SELECT Id, Email, Name FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name = 'Regional Manager'];
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<User> users) {
        EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'Expiry_Notification' LIMIT 1];
        for (User u: users) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(emailTemplate.Id, UserInfo.getUserId(), u.Id);
            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            email.setToAddresses(new List<String> { u.Email });

            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] mailResult = Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.Email> { email });
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        // Call another process
    }
}
```

The email grabs some extra data and prints it in a table in the email.

I can create a unit test what will create the required data for the process to run, the problem is that the unit test fails at `Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate()` with the error:

```java
System.EmailTemplateRenderException: EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MERGEFIELD_ERROR: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

My suspicion is that even though I have created the correct data for the unit test, when it is trying to render the email, it is not running in the same context as the unit test. Thus it can't see any of the test data that I have created.

One way that I can work around this is that I can annotate my test method with `SeeAllData = true` but given that my org might not have the data that is needed for the process/email (I am currently testing this in my dev org), I don't think the is the best solution.

Is there a way that I can create test data in a unit test and make it visible to when the visualforce email template when running a unit test?

I have tried using the `Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate()` function as well as configuring the `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage()` object:

```java
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);
mail.setWhatId(u.Id);
mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
mail.setToAddresses(new List<String> { u.Email });
```

Comment: it would help if you can show test class also

Answer (score 0):

Signature of renderStoredEmailTemplate is `renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, whoId, whatId)`. The 2nd parameter should be lead, contact or user `Id` and 3rd parameter can be any other object (like account or opportunity). This could be the possible reason.

I believe, you are trying to send an email to each user retrieved from start method, so targetObjectId should be that user so that merge fields can be properly set. And whatId should be one of 
Account,
Asset,
Campaign,
Case,
Contract,
Opportunity,
Order,
Product,
Solution,
Custom. It makes more sense of setting whatId if the targetObjectId/whoId is contact.

Try this:

```
global System.Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return [SELECT Id, Email, Name FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name = 'Regional Manager'];
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<User> users) {
    EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'Expiry_Notification' LIMIT 1];
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for (User u: users) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);
        email.setTargetObjectId(u.Id);
        email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        email.setToAddresses(new List<String> { u.Email });
        messages.add(email);
    }
    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    //
}
```